# .htaccess rewrite not handling error pages correctly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a static website build using .php files spread around a small directory structure.

I use the following rewrite to expose my pages without the .php extension :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

This works but when I request a non-existent page the server returns a 500 error instead of a 404.  I don't understand why.

I want to send requests to missing pages to a file in the document root called 404.php and exposed as just '404', but to do this I first need the server to correctly return a 404 error, rather than 500.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your are rewriting everything that doesn't exist on your site to `$1.php` .

You need to check if the uri exists as a php file before rewriting the request
.

Try

```
RewriteEngine on 
#if the uri.php exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
# rewrite the uri
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks.  Works perfectly.